# Hola, me estoy adentrando en el terreno de la programación y quisiera saber que funciones o condicionales usar en python

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de realizar algo como la creación de un usuario que tiene ciertas restricciones, pero me gustaría que el código solo termine su ejecución al momento de que se cumpla la condición de que el usuario es correcto, si no es así, que le de nuevamente la opción de crear su usuario.

```
Usuario = input("ingrese un nombre de usuario: ")

while True:
    
    if len(Usuario)<6:
        print("El usuario debe tener mas de 6 Caracteres") 
        continue
        
    elif len(Usuario)>15:   
        print("el usuario no puede contener mas de 12 caracteres")
        continue
    else:
        print("el usuario ha sido guardado con exito")
        print("hola "+ Usuario)
        break
```

Comment: Eso se logra mediante un ciclo `while`

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Para llevar a cabo lo que deseas necesitas usar un bucle [`while`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) o [`for`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) (este último para un número concreto de repeticiones).

Comment: @Christian, al usar el while me repite de forma indefinida al no cumplir las condiciones, solo si se ejecuta de forma correcta continua normal, no se si me explico

Comment: Por favor, comparte el código que has probado con el bucle `while` para que podamos revisar qué está ocurriendo. Sin ver el código no podemos adivinar qué está mal en el código ni podremos ayudarte a solucionarlo.

Comment: Para el detener el `while` usas un `break`

Comment: Buenas ideas para aprender a programar: 1. Acostumbrarse a seguir la documentación oficial, inclusive los problemas más comunes o los `knowing issue` se encuentran ahí junto con la solución o `work around`. 2. Seguir tutoriales tanto en video como en texto: https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/pythonya/ 3. Aprender inglés, esto es un diferencial enorme entre los que se niegan a aprenderlo y los que se han expandido a lo grande al tenerlo de aliado. 4. Aprender a formular preguntas, aquí unas recomendaciones desde mi punto de vista https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correcciones:

Los nombres de variable empiezan con minúsculas; las mayúsculas se reservan para nombres de Clases.

Tienes que pedir el usuario dentro del `while`, cada vez que sea necesario. Actualmente lo pides una sola vez, y el usuario no tiene posibilidades de corregir un mal ingreso.

No tienes para que usar `continue`; no hay ninguna otra línea de código que saltar después de fallar la validación.

Es mejor calcular el largo solo una vez. Si lo calculas dos veces alguien pensaria que el largo cambió entre un `if` y otro. Con eso le obligas a revisar el código buscando ese cambio.

Es mejor imprimir el usuario fuera del `while`. Eso expresa mejor el ser un resultado final, algo que se hará solo una vez.

```
while True:
    usuario = input("ingrese un nombre de usuario: ")
    largo = len(usuario)
    if largo < 6:
        print("El usuario debe tener mas de 6 Caracteres")
    elif largo > 15:
        print("el usuario no puede contener mas de 12 caracteres")
    else:
        break
        
print("el usuario ha sido guardado con exito")
print("hola " + usuario)
```